# What does determine the amount of time an "await" takes?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following code to read bytes from a TCP stream (I've removed error checking):

```cs
/// <summary>Awaitable. Reads a certain amount of bytes from a network stream. Returns false
/// on error</summary>
async Task<bool> readBytes (NetworkStream stream, byte []buffer, int totalBytes)
{
    int bytesRead = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        var br = await stream.ReadAsync (buffer, bytesRead, totalBytes - bytesRead);
        if (br == 0) return false;      // closed stream

        bytesRead += br;
        if (bytesRead >= totalBytes) return true;
    }
}
```

Then I use it externally to receive 4 bytes with the length of the data coming, and the body of data (pseudocode, I've removed error checking and allocation, just to give an idea):

```cs
success = await readBytes(stream, header, 4);
success = await readBytes(stream, data, dataLength);

presentDataToApp(data, dataLength);
```

The client/server must interact in almost realtime (it's a game where a client app adjusts several parameters, like i.e. lights). The client, in example, has a WinForms slider, and transmits all the changes into the server app. There can be a lot of updates in a single second when moving that slider (from my logs, it sends data around 100 times/second).

This code works well and in realtime, as long as the server (which runs the code I've pasted) is run through Visual Studio. However, when I run the server app without Visual Studio (or using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>) the communication starts lagging badly.

To discard an async/await problem, I cloned the comms class and run it through a Thread, removing all async/await functions. The code now runs realtime in both Visual Studio and standalone (so it is a problem related to async/await).

Why is async/await lagging communications in this case? (there's certainly lots of awaits in a second). What does determine the amount of time waited after an await that doesn't have the data ready takes? (I supposed it was the Timer Resolution, but it seems to be at 1ms on my system no matter how I execute the server app).

Comment: What happens when you run in Release mode?

Comment: async/await is not an isolated issue. Show us how you call this, in realtion to all other async or threading.

Comment: My first wild guess - your "sending" code starve your "receiving" code. Can you check, how many sends per second you do without visual studio? Also try setting hard limit (like let's say 50 times per second, as i doubt you need more) and see, if it helps.

Comment: It sounds like your window's message loop might be getting saturated, since that's how the continuations are actually brought back to the UI thread.

Comment: Also, little side note.  Your timer resolution isn't actually 1ms,  Windows won't give you any better resolution than about 13-14 ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The client/server must interact in almost realtime

I always recommend SignalR in any case where you control both client and server. It's just much easier to program against SignalR than raw sockets.

> This code works well and in realtime, as long as the server is run through Visual Studio. However, when I run the server app without Visual Studio (or using Ctrl+F5) the communication starts lagging badly.

This is extremely weird. VS is making your code run *faster?* I have no explanation for this.

> What does determine the amount of time waited after an await that doesn't have the data ready takes?

There's a couple of things going on here that could each have an impact.

The first is that `await` captures a context and resumes on that context. This is particularly a problem if it is a UI context. [At 100 updates per second, you're reaching the limit of what's practical](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/ui-guidelines-for-async.html). If your `await`s are resuming on the UI thread, you can avoid this kind of "performance death by a thousand paper cuts" by using `ConfigureAwait(false)`. If it is really `await` that is causing the slowdown, take time to review the [Zen of Async video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/BUILD2011/TOOL-829T).

The second is that there's a lot of memory churn. `readBytes` requires a separate array for each packet at least (assuming you reuse the header array), and there are also a number of `Task` instances around. **If** profiling suggests that the problem is memory churn, then [consider using the new `Memory<T>`-based socket APIs that avoid the byte arrays, as well as the new `ValueTask<T>`-based APIs which avoid the `Task` allocations when the data is already arrived](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/understanding-the-whys-whats-and-whens-of-valuetask/). E.g., the .NET Core 2.1 `Stream` API `ValueTask<int> ReadAsync(Memory<byte> buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken);` If profiling suggests the problem is memory churn but you're not on .NET Core 2.1 yet, then you can use the [`SocketAsyncEventArgs` APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/awaiting-socket-operations/).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. The problem was that I was calling that code from UI thread despite it didn't need to be called from UI.  Reading the first link made me think that maybe that was the problem. What puzzles me is the VS behaviour.